# Use Google's App Engine framework to read a mail and extract its attachments?

Tags: google-app-engine, email, email-attachments

I'm developing a tool that lets an user receive some data through an email account, in the form of a regular file. The goal is to implement this:

file → email attachment → canbeanything@myapp.com → system backend copies attachment.

Can I use Google's App Engine to develop this application? I have read their documentation on handling email but I think it's bound to just the admin's account. Can you explain me the process for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine application can receive emails to a specific list of address. If `my-app-id` is your application then any email ending with `@my-app-id.appspotmail.com` will be sent to your application.

For example the following emails are valid destinations that will be received by your app :

- `hello@my-app-id.appspotmail.com`
- `no-reply@my-app-id.appspotmail.com`
- ...

Note that even if you app has a custom domain like `myapp.com`, the destination email address will remain in `@my-app-id.appspotmail.com`. You can probably circumvent this by configuring your domain's email settings to forward all emails to App Engine.

Once received by the App Engine infrastructure, the emails are POSTed to a specific URL of your app, where you can write a handler (a Servlet in Java) to process the email content and save it somewhere. Here is the [Python documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail) on receiving email, and the [Java documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving).

Note that there probably is a limit to the size of attachments you can receive this way. I expect something along the line of 25Mo, which is GMail's attachment limit or 32Mo which is App Engine's POST request size limit.

Once you receive an email, I strongly recommend you perform the processing in a task queue, to avoid temporary issues (out of memory, faulty process) that would lead to the email being lost.

When it comes to saving the attachment, consider using Google Cloud Storage, since the Datastore is limited to 1Mb per entity.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Just a question to expand the information: Is that list of addresses regulated by something? I mean, I know I should have to buy more "names" to my domain registrar service but do I have to also pay Google for the names in the email list?

Comment: There is no list and no additional cost. Any address that respects the pattern works already.